# Add eObject to the parse tree programmatically

Tags: factory, xtext, parse-tree

Here is a snapshot of my grammar:

```
Sort:
 name=ID 
;
Variable
 name=ID ':' type=[Sort]
```

My requirement is to have a predefined *Sort* let's call it **Loc**. There is no need for the user to define this sort, thus when a *Variable* is defined with a **Loc** type, Xtext should automatically reference it to my predefined Sort. How can I initiate the program so that at the beginning a Sort instance is generated? I already used the Factory method 'CreateSort' in my *validator* class, but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition with createSort Factory method is good but you have to call it at the right time.
The **Loc** instance must be created before linking step. To do so, you have to bind a custom Linker and override it.

```
public class CustomLinker extends LazyLinker {

    @Override
    protected void beforeModelLinked(EObject model,
            IDiagnosticConsumer diagnosticsConsumer) {
        super.beforeModelLinked(model, diagnosticsConsumer);
        if (model instanceof Root) {
            Root root = (Root) model;
            Sort locSort = MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createSort();
            locSort.setName("Loc");
            root.getContent().add(locSort);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you bind this custom linker class in Runtime Module:

```
public class MyDslRuntimeModule extends org.xtext.example.mydsl.AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends ILinker> bindILinker() {
        return CustomLinker.class;
    }
}
```

Now you can write a file containing

> variable : Loc

The reference will be resolved.

Comment: Tnx man, i'm going to try this solution, just to get clear, what exactly is 'Program'? Does it refer to my root grammar rule?