# how to solve this for JIt ecore xtext DSL

Tags: dsl, xtext, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I have this grammar

```
MyEStructuralFeature returns ecore::EStructuralFeature:
    {ecore::EAttribute} name=ID ':'  (eType=[ ecore::EDataType|MyDefaultDataType] (defaultValueLiteral=MyValue)?)
    | {ecore::EReference} name=ID ':' (eType=[ecore::EClass])
;

MyEClass returns ecore::EClass:
    {ecore::EClass} name=ID (NEWLINE eStructuralFeatures+=MyEStructuralFeature)+;

MyDataType returns ecore::EDataType:
    {Boolean} name='Boolean'
    | {Integer} name='Integer'
    | {Number} name='Number'
    | {String} name='String'
    | {UUID} name='UUID';

MyDefaultDataType:
    'Boolean' | 'Integer' | 'Number' | 'String' | 'UUID';
```

the issue with this grammar is that I can't get any EAttribute created as well as the code assist of the defined types (MyDataType )
so how to get this working

```
Student
       age:String    //getting error here as it can't resolve String

School
      students:Student
```

thank you

Comment: Your grammar doesn't show where your datatypes are declared, can you edit it?

Comment: Hi, yes in fact MyDataType is the name of the rule, nevertheless could this be achieved via the override of the Linker ?

Comment: Yes you can: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738815/add-eobject-to-the-parse-tree-programaticaly